# Looking for an efficient Interval tree Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, tree, complexity-theory, intervals

I have a set of objects which store intervals given by the low and high value. I'm searching for a data struture, which will allow me to get all objects, whose intervals overlap with a given point in real-time. I also need to be able to add and delete single objects as fast as possible. [Interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) based on Red-Black trees have O(log n) insertion and deletion time and O(n) space. But the query to find all overlaps takes O(k log n) time, which can be worse than brute-force search, if there are many overlapping intervals. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interval trees are made for this job.  Finding all the intervals that overlap a point takes O(k + log n) time, not O(k log n).

This is the "centered interval tree" as mentioned in your wikipedia link.  It's reasonable to implement one of these based on red-black trees:

- The main tree would be a red-black tree.  Each node would have its center point and interval lists.  You create a new node whenever you insert a new interval that doesn't overlap any existing center points.  You delete a node whenever you delete all of its center-point-overlapping intervals.
- The rotation operations performed to balance the RB-tree will require you to move some center-point-overlapping intervals up from child nodes to their new parents. Each node should store its lists of center-point-overlapping intervals in other red-black trees, so that this movement can be done in log(n) time.  Note that an RB tree does an amortized constant number of rotations per insert/delete.

However... since it seems that you have *not* already done this with RB-trees, and RB-trees are complicated, I would suggest doing the same thing with treaps instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treap

Treaps will be much easier than RB trees, because they're simpler to begin with, and they don't require rotations to keep them balanced, which makes it much easier to maintain the lists of center-point-overlapping intervals. Those intervals can be stored in treaps as well.

Much easier... but still not that easy :-)

Comment: Are we talking about RB-based trees, not the centered ones, right? How can we query such tree in O(k + log n)? I've read Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition, but there was only a  O(k log n) example.

Comment: A centered interval tree, where each node has a point, trees of intervals that overlap that point (same nodes, sorted 2 ways), and left + right children, using red-black balancing.  That's what I thought you were talking about. I don't think the "augmented tree" from the wikipedia link is properly called an "interval tree".

Comment: Sorry for being incorrect, i was talking about the augmented tree first. That one can query in O(k log n), i believe. The centered one seems to have a faster query speed, but what about adding and deleting elements? Can it be done in O(log n)?

Comment: Yes. I added some implementation notes for that